# Cadence encounter power analysis

Tags: power, verilog, modelsim, cadence

I have written a verilog code for a circuit (test.v) and a testbench (testd_tb.v). I use these commands for generating the power using cadence encounter RTL compiler.
I have made 3 folders. Work, RTL(where all .v files are stored), Library (which has slow_normal.lib).
In the work folder I type these commands :

1. rc -gui (to invoke the encounter tool)
2. set_attribute lib_search_path ../library
3. set_attribute hdl_search_path ../rtl
4. set_attribute library slow_normal.lib
5. read {test.v}
6. elaborate
7. synthesize -to_mapped
8. report power

The above commands help me to generate the power for the design but I am unable to get test bench specific power output. Kindly do suggest me the changes that can be made in this code.

Answer (score 1):

1. Testbenches need not be read into synthesis tool
2. Testbench is used to simulate verilog code

You need the TCF file from simulator to generate accurate power reports.